# storing hashMap in a hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

i am reading data from a text file and want to store HashMap in another HashMap..

```
HashMap<string,HashMap<string,value>>
```

how to store data and retrieve it?
any sample code will be appreciated...
thank u

Answer (score 40):

Example:

Creating and populating the maps

```
Map<String, Map<String, Value>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Value>>();
Map<String, Value> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Value>();    
innerMap.put("innerKey", new Value());
```

Storing a map

```
outerMap.put("key", innerMap);
```

Retrieving a map and its values

```
Map<String, Value> map = outerMap.get("key");
Value value = map.get("innerKey");
```

Comment: Note: in java its `String` with a upper S.

Comment: Edit:
Map<String, Map<String, Value>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Value>>();

I was getting a type mismatch exception.

Comment: @Johan What if I need to update the inner map after putting it in the outer map? Can that be done?

Comment: @Sohaib You would have to get() the innerMap, update it then put it again.

Comment: @LukeChamberlain I don't think put() again is required since the get would return a reference. Just get() and updating it would be enough. I did some experiments yesterday and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Creating two Simple Hashmaps: InnerMap and OuterMap

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Populating the HashMaps

```
    innerMap.put("InnerKey", "InnerValue");
    outerMap.put("OuterKey", innerMap);
```

Retreiving values from HashMaps

```
    String value = ((HashMap<String, String>)outerMap.get("OuterKey")).get("InnerKey").toString();
    System.out.println("Retreived value is : " + value);
```

Comment: There is no use to store the _same instance_ of `innerMap` for each key in `outerMap`, it would be the same as not having `outerMap`. You should create a new instance of the "inner map" for each new key in `outerMap`.

Comment: @Trinidad: Thats absolutely correct. For each new key in outermap there will be a new instance of innerMap. I was just trying to demonstrate "how to populate the value in outermap with one key, and then just retreiving its value".

Comment: Oh, but it confuses to instantiate both maps in the same place, you should have put the creation of the new inner map instance with the code to populate it. =)

Comment: So you are nesting Hashmaps, but just to avoid retrieving the inner one, you recreate it each time. That's a waste of performance.

Answer (score 4):

You get something that looks like a 2 dimensions HashMap, so to say. Which means you need 2 String to store a value, and also to retrieve one.

You could, for example write a class to wrap that complexity, like that (untested code):

```
public class HashMap2D<T> {
    private HashMap<String,HashMap<String,T>> outerMap;

    public HashMap2D() {
        outerMap = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,T>>();
    }

    public void addElement(String key1, String key2, T value) {
        innerMap=outerMap.get(key1);
        if (innerMap==null) {
            innerMap = new HashMap<String,T>();
            outerMap.put(key1,innerMap);
        }
        innerMap.put(key2,value);
    }

    public T getElement(String key1, String key2) {
        Hashmap innerMap = outerMap.get(key1);
        if (innerMap==null) {
            return null;
        }
        return innerMap.get(key2);
    }
}
```

If you want methods to process more than one data at a time, it's more complicated, but follows the same principles.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve the same problem using one map (although, this does not directly answer your question) by flattening two nested maps into one big map, using a double-key.

```
public class Key2D{
  private final String outer;
  private final String inner;

  public Key2D(String outer, String inner){
    this.outer = outer;
    this.inner = inner;
  }

  //include default implementations for
  //Object.equals(Object) and Object.hashCode()
  //Tip: If you're using Eclipse it can generate
  //them for you.
}
```

Then just create one map with double-key:

```
Map<Key2D, Value> map = new HashMap<Key2D, Value>();
map.put(new Key2D("outerKey", "innerKey"), "Value");
map.get(new Key2D("outerKey", "innerKey")); // yields "Value"
```

This gives a shorter solution. Performance wise it's probably about the same. Memory performance is probably slightly better (just guessing, though).

Answer (score 0):

HashMap in HashMap will cause problems in readability especially when it goes beyond two levels. I assume that when you read data from a text file you want to categorize the inputs from rows and columns which should be similar to multi-level categories or category within a category. If you can post the sample data and your intention, I could come up with a Custom class example.

```
public class Category {
  private List<Category> subCategories;
  private List<Item> items;
}
```

The above data structure will help you solve any level of nesting while categorizing data. This example is specific to a store items' classification.