# How do I iterate over a LinkedHashMap of LinkedHashMaps?

Tags: java

My map looks like this :

```
LinkedHashMap <LinkedHashMap <String,String>,LinkedHashMap <String,String>> leftRightWords
```

Where the first map contains left words of a proper noun and second map contains right words of a proper noun. E.g. in :

> "Following the Rhode Island solution provider Atrion's decision to
>   sell"

map1 will have entries like:

```
Rhode Island, Following the 
Atrion, solution provider
```

map2 will have entries like:

```
Rhode Island, solution provider
Atrion, decision to sell
```

In both maps the keys are the same but the values differ based on left and right words. How do i iterate over this map to extract the left words and right words to analyze them?

Comment: I read this, it seems that you need a better data structure for it. E.g. multiMap or something like that, since you said the key in both inner maps are always same.  However i cannot further suggest, because I don't know the exact requirement.

Comment: Are both `Map`'s `keySet`s guaranteed to be of the same `size`?

Comment: This seems like a weird choice of types, why not have a `Words` class, which holds both left and right, and have a  `Map<String, Words>`. Or maybe also store the noun itself and just have a `List<Words>`.

Comment: @CraigR8806 Yes..they will be of the same size.

Comment: @serendipity see my answer then, it should accomplish what you are requesting

Comment: @CraigR8806 Lamda expressions are a part of Java8 right? I'm restricted to Java 6 as I'm building this on top of the Stanford NLP libraries which require Java 6.

Comment: @serendipity Any restrictions should be listed in your original post.  I will modify it to be compatible with J6, however it will be more verbose

Comment: Are you sure that you need Java6? Even if the library needs to be compiled under java6, you still should be able to use it under java8.

Comment: @CraigR8806 Should I convert this to a multi map like Kent suggested? I want to keep this solution simple. And if multi map is the way to go then how does one implement one?

Comment: afaik multimap is not in the Java standard library. Besides, using a class helps keep things simple, because it adds a layer of abstract.

Comment: serendipity I have edited my answer to be compatible with Java 6.  It may benefit you more to look into a different data model like @Kent suggested, if you have the luxury of having the ability of changing your model.  Sometimes projects are so big that to change a model would mean millions of lines of rewrite

Comment: @JornVernee I know this looks unwieldy...This is not an easy probem to solve to begin with i.e. identifying Named Entities and classifying based on surrounding context. The reason why I chose this type is coz I have a method that iterates over a sentence and all the proper nouns found in it to extract left and right words. I wanted to return both left and right words in that method but since we can return only one value I decided to return a map of two maps. The keys help in associating the correct surrounding words to the proper noun as there can be multiple proper nouns in a sentence.

Comment: In that case you should go with the `List<Words>`, where `Words` is just a tuple for the 3 values, the class would do the association, but you get rid of this complex data structure.

Comment: Similar to the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120216/map-of-maps-how-to-keep-the-inner-maps-as-maps , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093718/map-of-maps-data-structure , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056708/storing-hashmap-in-a-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested `forEach` loop to extract the data you desire, like so:

```
for(LinkedHapMap<String, String> lhm: leftRightWords.keySet()){
    for(String k:lhm.keySet()){
       String left = lhm.get(k);
       String right = leftRightWords.get(lhm).get(k);
       //do something with these Strings
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Iterator<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> resultKeys = leftRightWords
                    .keySet().iterator();
            while (resultKeys.hasNext()) {
                LinkedHashMap<String, String> tempKey = resultKeys.next();
                LinkedHashMap<String, String> tempVal = leftRightWords.get(tempKey);
                System.out.println("Key:");
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tempKey.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "   "
                            + entry.getValue());
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Value:");
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tempVal.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "   "
                            + entry.getValue());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
```